# Haskell - non-numeric string as integer

Tags: string, haskell, integer

I'm trying to convert a non-numeric string to an integer, and back again. That is, I need a way to represent a string, for example "Hello world!" as a unique integer, which then can be converted back into the same string. However, I have no idea how to do this, especially not in Haskell which is a language I only been using for a couple of weeks.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a good question for Stackoverflow. If you want a pointer on this, however, look at [gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering).

Comment: I guess the prevailing question is going to be *why* you think you need to do that?

Comment: @AdamSmith This is a probably an exercise.

Comment: @AJFarmar kind of a strange exercise. "Use haskell to turn a string into a unique number?" Hrm. Maybe "Turn a string into a series of bytes" or "serialize a string" or even "using any language, design an algorithm that turns a sequence of characters into a unique number," but this specific thing seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @AdamSmith Can you say carefully what you see as the difference, in principle, between "turn a string into a unique number" and "serialize a string"?

Comment: @DanielWagner The way an instructor might explain it to a student who doesn't know how to approach the problem :)

Comment: @AJFarmar It's correct that I taking a class in functional programming at the moment, however this is not part of one of the exercises. In math class we spent half a lecture talking about RSA encryption, and as an exercise for myself I wanted to implement the algorithm in Haskell. But for that to work I needed a way to represent a message (a string) as a number.

Answer (score 7):

You may use [`readInt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:readInt) and [`showIntAtBase`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showIntAtBase), included in the standard library that ships with GHC, for this task.

```
Numeric> base = toInteger (fromEnum (maxBound :: Char)) + 1
Numeric> readInt base (const True) fromEnum "Hello, world!"
[(263317223602531232689798224281528500955719219481801413146983858530815311905,"")]
Numeric> showIntAtBase base toEnum 263317223602531232689798224281528500955719219481801413146983858530815311905 ""
"Hello, world!"
```

There is one small caveat: you'll want to write a wrapper that handles the empty string somehow -- perhaps map it to `-1`, or bump all the other answers up by `1` or something. On the up side, though, this particular pair of functions has a nice property you didn't demand, namely, every (non-negative) integer corresponds to a unique string.